# How to work with image sizes for different resolutions for a website?

Tags: images, performance, optimization

On a casual desktop pc with 1920x1080px you would take an image with 1080px width for a background or slider image, but a website visitor with a WHQL resolution, would get a small or upscaled image what could makes it pixelated.

On the other hand a small device like a mobile phone would never need an image with 1080px width so it would be bad for performance to load the big image and let the browser downscaling.

Is there a recommended way for that purpose which is also well supported?

Answer (score 3):

### `srcset`

> The `srcset` and `sizes` attributes on `img` (or `source`) elements allow authors to define various image resources and "hints" that assist a user agent to determine the most appropriate image source to display (e.g. high-resolution displays, small monitors, etc).

### Browser Support

[image: caniuse srcset]

Very well supported. If you are concerned about IE still there are a number of polyfills, [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) is a popular one.

### Example Usage

**Normal image:**

```html
<img src="example-image-800w.jpg">
```

**Resizing With `srcset`:**

```html
<img srcset="example-image-480w.png 480w,
             example-image-800w.png 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="example-image-800w.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

I would generally have different images for each size screen and use css @media queries to display the different images or change content as required.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp